# Is it possible to use the Single Sign On Service (currently only available on US) from an app deployed on UK?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I get that it wont be possible to bind the service and therefore not use the `VCAP_SERVICES`, and credentials would need to be managed in another way.

Since the communication would go via the internet, I guess the question is really:

Does the SSO service have an API that can be reached from outside of Bluemix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the SSO service can be reached from outside Bluemix and therefore also from apps deployed on UK.

However, to retrieve the credentials you need to create an SSO service on US and then bind an app to it and inspect the `VCAP_SERVICES`. This is due to how Cloud Foundry works. Read more [here](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES)